# predict.gls fails when the package "MuMin" is installed in R

Tags: r, predict, nlme, mumin

**I am getting an error message when using predict.gls when the package "MuMIn" is installed.**

The following (Ex. 1) works:

```
### EX. 1

library(nlme)

# example code from https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/predict.gls.html

fm1 <- gls(follicles ~ sin(2*pi*Time) + cos(2*pi*Time), Ovary,
           correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | Mare))
newOvary <- data.frame(Time = c(-0.75, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.75))
predict(fm1, newOvary)

# [1]  9.441686 13.116003 11.316793 13.116003 14.991110
# attr(,"label")
# [1] "Predicted values"
```

However, the following (Ex. 2) yields an error message, even though the library(MuMIn) line is the only difference from Ex. 1:

```
### EX. 2

library(nlme)
library(MuMIn) # (This is the only thing different from Ex. 1)

# example code from https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/predict.gls.html

fm1 <- gls(follicles ~ sin(2*pi*Time) + cos(2*pi*Time), Ovary,
           correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | Mare))
newOvary <- data.frame(Time = c(-0.75, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.75))
predict(fm1, newOvary)

# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'follicles' not found
```

**Does anyone know why this is the case? There seems to be an incompatibility when using 'predict' when MuMIn is installed**

Interestingly, the following (Ex. 3), which calls predict.gls directly, restores it to working:

```
### EX. 3

library(nlme)
library(MuMIn) 

# example code from https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/predict.gls.html

fm1 <- gls(follicles ~ sin(2*pi*Time) + cos(2*pi*Time), Ovary,
       correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | Mare))
newOvary <- data.frame(Time = c(-0.75, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.75))
nlme:::predict.gls(fm1, newOvary) # (This is the only thing different from Ex. 2)

# [1]  9.441686 13.116003 11.316793 13.116003 14.991110
# attr(,"label")
# [1] "Predicted values"
```

However, I have read that it is inadvisable to use 'nlme:::predict.gls' as the ':::' can be 'risky' because it accesses internal functions that aren't meant to be directly available.

Here is my current R.version output:

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          3
minor          4.0
year           2017
month          04
day            21
svn rev        72570
language       R
version.string R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
nickname       You Stupid Darkness

Incidentally, I didn't have this problem on my old computer, which used an older version of R. I had a friend try Ex. 2 on his computer, and it produced an error message too.

**Any insight into the reason for the error message in Ex. 2, and how I can fix it without resorting to the workaround in Ex. 3, would be much appreciated!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"MuMIn" implements its own `predict.gls` method which allows for `se.fit`, but as it turns out it may have a bug. If you load "nlme" **after** "MuMIn", the original method from "nlme" will be used.

**Edit:** This is fixed now. Please update MuMIn to version 1.16.5, from R-Forge:
`install.packages("MuMIn", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

Comment: Thank you, @KamilBartoń, updating MuMIn using your method (in the "Edit") did the trick and it appears to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

A way to bypass the problem is to use the function `MuMIn:::predict.gls` adding to the `newdata` dataset the response variable `follicles`. You can input random values to the response variables, they will be not used in the calculation.

```
library(nlme)
library(MuMIn)

fm1 <- gls(follicles ~ sin(2*pi*Time) + cos(2*pi*Time), Ovary,
                   correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | Mare))
newOvary <- data.frame(Time = c(-0.75, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.75), follicles=rep(1,5))
predict(fm1, newOvary)

############
[1]  9.441686 13.116003 11.316793 13.116003 14.991110
attr(,"label")
[1] "Predicted values"
```

These estimates are exactly the same given by `nlme:::predict.gls`

```
nlme:::predict.gls(fm1)
[1]  9.441686 13.116003 11.316793 13.116003 14.991110
attr(,"label")
[1] "Predicted values"
```